# aws dms 移行タスクについてです。

Tags: aws

aws postgre から aws sqlserver に移行しようとしています。

aws dms の移行タスクを実行しましたが、タスクステータスロード完了しました。

しかし、テーブル移行は一切されなかったようです。

ログをみると

```
[SOURCE_UNLOAD] I：ODBC接続文字列に接続しようとしています
[TARGET_LOAD] I：最大行サイズの警告を無視するようにバルクが設定されています
```

が出ています。

ソースエンドポイントとターゲットエンドポイントのレプリケーションインスタンス接続は全部できています。
タスクも異常なし、ロードは完了していますが、テーブル移行されない原因がわからないので、
ご存じの方々教えて頂けたら幸いです。

**詳細手順：**

1. レプリケーションインスタンスを作成
2. ソースエンドポイントを作成
   ・ソースエンドポイントとレプリケーションインスタンスの接続テスト成功
3. ターゲットエンドポイントを作成
   ・ターゲットエンドポイントとレプリケーションインインスタンスの接続テスト成功
4. 移行タスク作成
   ・ステータスはロード完了
   ⇒ソースのテーブルデータが送信されない、ターゲットにテーブルデータが受信されない、
   つまり、テーブル移行タスクがされてないです。

Comment: 該当部分のログはエラーではないようなので、より詳細に手順を記載すると回答が得られやすくなるかもしれません。こちらも合わせてご確認ください。[AWS Database Migration Service での移行タスクのトラブルシューティング - AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html)

Comment: @PicoSushi  さん、ありがとうございます。詳細手順を追加で記載しておりました。